# My code is woring in mongodb but not working in pymongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have a documents in collection and I want to find document and update elements of list.

Here is sample data:

```
 { 
    {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5edd3faaf6c9d938e0bfd966"),
       "id" : 1,
       "status" : "XXX",
        "number" : [
                        {
                          "code" : "AAA"
                         },
                        {
                          "code" : "CVB"
                        },
                       {
                          "code" : "AAA"
                       },
                       {
                          "code" : "BBB"
                       }
                   ]
    },
    {
       "_id" : ObjectId("asseffsfpo2dedefwef"),
       "id" : 2,
       "status" : "TUY",
        "number" : [
                        {
                          "code" : "PPP"
                         },
                        {
                          "code" : "SSD"
                        },
                       {
                          "code" : "HDD"
                       },
                       {
                          "code" : "IOO"
                       }
                   ]
       }
  }
```

I planed to find where `"id":1` and value of `number.code` in `["AAA", "BBB"]`, change `number.code` to `"DDD"`. I did it with following code:

```
db.test.update(
    {
        id: 1,
        "number.code": {$in: ["AAA", "BBB"]}
    },
    {
        $set: {"number.$[elem].code": "VVV"}
    },
        { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.code": {$in: ["AAA", "BBB"]} }], "multi": true, "upsert": false 
    }
)
```

It works in mongodb shell, but in python (with `pymongo`) it doesn't with the following error:

```
raise TypeError("%s must be True or False" % (option,))
TypeError: upsert must be True or False
```

Please help me. What can I do?

Comment: I believe `true` in python is `True` & `false` is `False` !! Change those Boolean typos and test it..moreover options `multi` & `upsert` both defaults to `false` you need to specify them only if you wanted those as `true` i.e; `True`

Answer (score 1):

`pymongo` just has syntax that's a tad different. it would look like this:

```
db.test.update_many(
    {
        "id": 1,
        "number.code": {"$in": ["AAA", "BBB"]}
    },
    {
        "$set": {"number.$[elem].code": "VVV"}
    },
    array_filters=[{"elem.code": {"$in": ["AAA", "BBB"]}}],
    upsert=False
)
```

- `multi` flag not needed with `update_many`.
- `upsert` is `False` by default hence also redundant.

You can find pymongo's docs [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html).